# Trying to setup a QUERY in Google Sheets and join results with Headers as labels

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm looking for help with trying to combine information from a query into a single cell, but also getting labels at the same time. 
This Query() with a nested Join() give me an error, saying it can't pull more than 1 column. Is there any way to implement  what I'm looking for below?

`=if(B2="","No Name Selected",join(char(10),query(J2:N5,"Select J,K,L,M,N Where J = '"&B2&"'",1)))`

Trying to join info from Query, but want to include headers as labels
**Headers**

`Name
Address
Phone Number
DOB
Email`

**Data**

`Sam Spud
102 Main St, Los Angeles, CA 90210
323-323-3233
1/2/2020
samspade@email.com`

**What I'm trying to get as the end result**

`Name: Sam Spade
Address: 101 Main St, Los Angeles, CA 90210
Phone Number: 323-323-3232
DOB: 1/1/2020
Email: samspade@email.com`

Created a sample page if anyone cares to try it out.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gUhJlrZbwtKB-xtn6nsGf58IO1wvD5T8O6STh17-FfY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2="",,SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 QUERY({"♦"&E2:I2&":"; TO_TEXT(E3:I)}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col1 = '"&B2&"'", 1)
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), "^♦", ), "♦", CHAR(10))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, what is the "♦" character? I've never seen it used before.

Comment: just a unique symbol used to be exchanged for char(10) - new line

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm trying to better understand the solution so I can implement it best, however i'm not sure I'm understanding the 999^99 in the query.

Comment: 999^99 is a big number. could be any number you wish but it needs to be higher than total number of rows in sheet

Comment: Great! thanks for the help. I think I've understood enough of it to implement it with different sheets I've got.